# My positions are the same, but nodes are not in the same place?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, scenekit

In my SceneKit scene I have a node that is a ball that the player will interact with and a camera, the camera is the child of an object called "selfieStick", which will follow on the ball and provide the so to say frame for the camera to focus the ball in. When I am implementing this I am doing so with the following code:

```
func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, updateAtTime time: TimeInterval) {
    let ball = ballNode?.presentation
    let ballPosition = ball?.position

    selfieStickNode?.position = ballPosition!
}
```

but when I run the game and tap the ball (making it jump forward), the selfie stick and ball go two different directions from each other... once I open the scene inspector and go into the scene I examine the positions of everything and the positions are the same for the ball and seflieStick, as they should be.... but the nodes aren't in the same spot in the scene... screenshots below.

[image: side angle]
[image: selfieStick selected]
[image: Ball in relation to selfieStick]

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out... for some reason the selfieStick was going in the opposite Z direction every time... so I fixed it with the following code:

```
func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, updateAtTime time: TimeInterval) {
    let ball = ballNode?.presentation
    let ballPosition = ball?.position
    let finalPosition = SCNVector3(ballPosition!.x,
                                   ballPosition!.y,
                                   (ballPosition!.z * -1))

    selfieStickNode?.position = finalPosition
}
```